# Escape dash in ant argument

Tags: xml, ant, escaping, build.xml

I trying to exlude a file from being checked in an Ant task. Todo that I need to add a argument to the command. This works fine for other files I try to exclude except for filepaths with dashes and spaces.

To wrap it up:

This does work

```
<arg line="--exclude=/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" />
```

This not

```
<arg line="--exclude=/jquery - foo/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" />
```

I've already tried to escape it like the linux shell does but that does not fix the problem.
Does anyone known how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` not `line`:

```
<arg value="--exclude=/jquery - foo/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" />
```

When you use `line` the value is split up on the spaces in to multiple arguments. When you use `value` there is no splitting.